# React Native Debugging In Google Chrome Not Working(Files not showing up in debugger)

Tags: android, ios, debugging, react-native, react-native-debugger

Normally when we click on the `Debug JS Remotely` option a new tab opens up in the `google chrome`(like in the below screenshot).

[image]

So as seen in the above screenshot we get all the `files` that we are working on according to the `directory`.

But in my case the `files` don't show up in the `chrome`(like in the below screenshot)

[image]

What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 6):

**1**. Choose "Open file" from this menu:

[image: open files in debugger]

**2**. Search for the file by typing its name:

[image]

**3**. Enjoy debugging!

Comment: how to add whole folder in chrome-debug-menu?